# How do I get OSSEC manage_agents to read a file?

Tags: ossec

According to the help docs of manage_clients:

> -f    Bulk generate client keys from file. (Manager only).
>                    contains lines in IP,NAME format.

So I tried this:

```
root@ossec-server:/var/ossec/etc# /var/ossec/bin/manage_agents -f /tmp/agent
Bulk load file: /tmp/agent
Opening: [/tmp/agent]
Failed.: No such file or directory
2015/05/16 15:07:34 manage_agents(1103): ERROR: Unable to open file '/tmp/agent'.
```

Even with full access:

```
root@ossec-server:/var/ossec/etc# ls -l /tmp/agent 
-rw-r--r-- 1 777 root 16 May 16 14:57 /tmp/agent
```

Content seems good:

```
root@ossec-server:/var/ossec/etc# cat /tmp/agent 
127.0.0.1,agent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having just cleared this hurdle, maybe I can help.  You need to put the file in the `/var/ossec` directory (mine has owner/group as `ossec`) and the **DO NOT** use the full path.

Example

```
/var/ossec/bin/manage_agents -f /var/ossec/list_to_add.lst
```

will not work (IDK why but it never worked).  However,

```
/var/ossec/bin/manage_agents -f list_to_add.lst
```

will work.

Comment: I'm assuming this is correctI. I ended up using the dynamic client registration service (that's inherently insecure until the next version) in the end since it worked a lot better with our dynamic infrastructure and it's all behind a VPN anyways. OSSEC sure is user unfriendly!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so this has to be an answer.  Matt is correct.

> IDK why but it never worked

You have to use the path *inside the chroot* because ossec processes [chroot themselves](https://ossec-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/ossec.html#can-ossec-s-logs-be-saved-to-a-different-directory), as `addagent.c` (which becomes `manage_agents`) does [here](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/blob/ddfd2d62466e71116eb45da3cc6d48a018e97c65/src/addagent/main.c#L172).

So, if you put a file in `/var/ossec/tmp/foo` you need to call `manage_agents` like

`/var/ossec/bin/manage_agents -f /tmp/foo`

(`tmp/foo` also works).